# Difference between set and list for relationship mappings

Tags: sqlalchemy

What is the distinction between these two SQLAlchemy declarations?

```
class Test(Base):
    testvar: Mapped[list["Tester"]] = relationship()
```

vs

```
testvar: Mapped[set["Tester"]] = relationship()
```

I typically retrieve rows, not pure values, from the database. If it were pure values, I could understand the performance implications. When should I use a set instead of a list in SQLAlchemy?

Shouldn't set cause the creation of an UniqueConstraint?